# Right of way (per deed)

Tags: real-estate, maryland, land

Following image is from the plat of a lot I am interested to buy.

[image]

What does it mean buy 30' right of way (per deed)? Does it mean that I will not be able to do anything with that part of lot although I will own it?

TIA

Comment: It simply means that, a right-of-way exists, with the size given.  The legal obligations of a right-of-way differ from country to country, state to state.

Comment: Other terms you might see are "ingress" and "egress", which are fancy Latin-derived terms for "go in" and "go out".

Answer (score 4):

The deed should explain the details of the right of way.  This is often for neighbors who need to cross someone else's property to get to their own property.

You likely can do things there as long as what you do doesn't prevent people from using the right of way.

Comment: Also it would include the right for various utilities to use that property.  It could be burying a pipe or cables, placing a "box", or using the property to access other items.  The owner would have the responsibility of maintaining it though.